# How do you execute two simultaneous I/O bound tasks in ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms asynchronously?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, .net-4.5, async-await

How do you execute both of the below methods asynchronously (StoreInSql, StoreInOtherDatabase), and then wait for both results to return before setting the label output message?  Can this be done cleanly with the await keyword?  Thank you very much.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.RetryPolicies;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace UpdateStorage
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string email = "test@test.com";

            // It takes approximately 300 ms to store in SQL Azure
            bool sqlStorageSuccessful = MyAppStorage.StoreInSqlAzureViaEF(email);

            // It takes approximately 300 ms to store in Azure Table Storage
            bool otherdbStorageSuccessful = MyAppStorage.StoreInAzureTableStorage(email);

            if (sqlStorageSuccessful && otherdbStorageSuccessful)
            {
                labelOutputMessage.Text = "Successfully stored the email.";
            }
            else
            {
                labelOutputMessage.Text = "We couldn't store the email, sorry!";
            }

            // 300ms + 300ms = It takes 600ms for this Page_Load method to complete.
            // How can I write it using the "await" keyword so that it only takes ~ 300ms?
        }
    }
    public static class MyAppStorage
    {
        public static bool StoreInSqlAzureViaEF(string s)
        {
            try
            {
                using (MyDataModelContainer db = new MyDataModelContainer())
                {
                    Email e = new Email();
                    e.EmailAddress = s;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        public static bool StoreInAzureTableStorage(string s)
        {
            try
            {
                AzureEmailMessage a = new AzureEmailMessage();
                a.EmailAddress = s;
                a.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    public static class AzureStorage
    {
        private static string _ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=myaccount;AccountKey=mykey";

        static AzureStorage() { }

        private static CloudTable GetTableRef(string tableName)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_ConnectionString);
            CloudTableClient tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
            IRetryPolicy linearRetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), 10);
            tableClient.RetryPolicy = linearRetryPolicy;
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
            table.CreateIfNotExists();
            return table;
        }
        public static bool SaveObject(ITableEntity entity)
        {
            try
            {
                string tableName = entity.GetType().ToString();
                int lastNs = tableName.LastIndexOf(".");
                if (lastNs > 0)
                {
                    tableName = tableName.Substring(lastNs + 1);
                }
                CloudTable table = GetTableRef(tableName);
                TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(entity);
                table.Execute(insertOperation);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    public class AzureEmailMessage : TableEntity
    {
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public AzureEmailMessage() { }

        public bool Save()
        {
            return AzureStorage.SaveObject(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "best?"

Comment: Edited the question to clarify that the focus of the question is on asynchronous execution and then waiting.  Thank you for the primer.

Comment: Does `MyAppStorage` expose any asynchronous methods like `IAsyncResult BeginStoreInSql(` or `Task StoreInSqlAsync(` or would it be possible to modify the class to properly create them?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Scott - it's possible to modify the class and I've added it to the question - how would you rewrite all of this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is to use asynchronous database access (e.g., EF6):

```
public static class MyAppStorage
{
    public static Task<bool> StoreInSqlAsync(string s)
    {
        return FakeStorageJobAsync(s);
    }
    public static Task<bool> StoreInOtherDatabaseAsync(string s)
    {
        return FakeStorageJobAsync(s);
    }

    private static async Task<bool> FakeStorageJobAsync(string s)
    {
        // This simulates waiting on a SQL database, or a web service, or any other storage task.
        await Task.Delay(300);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you can consume them naturally using `Task.WhenAll` and `await`:

```
protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string email = "test@test.com";

    bool[] success = await Task.WhenAll(MyAppStorage.StoreInSqlAsync(email),
        MyAppStorage.StoreInOtherDatabaseAsync(email));
    if (success[0] && success[1])
    {
        labelOutputMessage.Text = "Successfully stored the email.";
    }
    else
    {
        labelOutputMessage.Text = "We couldn't store the email, sorry!";
    }
}
```

In this example, I'm using `async void` for simplicity, but the ASP.NET team prefers you to use `PageAsyncTask` [as described in the tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45).

Comment: Stephen, thank you very much for the reply.  I've edited the question to include an example of saving the object via SQL Azure EF and also with Azure Table Storage.  How would you write it in this case?  Thanks again!

Comment: Like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx) for EF6, and using the `*Async` methods for the Azure Table Storage.